# Extracting two signed integers from one given integer?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have the following structure:

```
struct
{
   int a:4;
   int b:7;
   int c:21;
} example;
```

I would like to combine a and b to form an integer d in C++. For instance, I would like the bit values of a to be on the left of the bit values of b in order to form integer d. How is this implemented in c++?

Example:

a= 1001

b = 1010101

I would like int d  =  10011010101 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

where x can be 21 bits that belonged to d previously. I would like the values of a and b to be put in bit positions 0-3 and 4-10 respectively since a occupies the first 4 bits and b occupies the next 7 bits in the struct "example".

The part that I am confused about is that variable a and variable b both have a "sign" bit at the most significant bit. Does this affect the outcome? Are all bits in variable a and variable b used in the end result for integer d? Will integer d look like a concatenation of variable a's bits and variable b's bits?

Thanks

Comment: How are you counting bit positions?  Normally, bit 0 is the least significant bit (LSB), and bit 31 is the most significant bit (MSB) of a 32-bit integer.  Your diagram suggests that you want bits 0-10 to be more significant than bits 11-31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that whether an `int` bit-field is signed or unsigned is implementation-defined.  The C++ standard says this, and the C standard achieves the same net result with different wording:

### ISO/IEC 14882:2011 — C++

> #### §7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers
>
> ¶3 ... [ Note: It is implementation-defined whether objects of `char` type and certain bit-fields (9.6) are
>   represented as signed or unsigned quantities. The `signed` specifier forces `char` objects and bit-fields to be
>   signed; it is redundant in other contexts. —end note ]
>
> #### §9.6 Bit-fields
>
> ¶3 ... A bit-field shall have integral or enumeration type (3.9.1). It is
>   implementation-defined whether a plain (neither explicitly signed nor unsigned) `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`,
>   or `long long` bit-field is signed or unsigned.

### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 — C

> #### §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> ¶10 A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits.<sup>125)</sup>
>
> <sup>125)</sup> As specified in 6.7.2 above, if the actual type specifier used is int or a typedef-name defined as int, then it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field is signed or unsigned.
>
> #### §6.7.2 Type specifiers
>
> ¶5 ... for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`.

The context of §6.7.2 shows that `int` can be combined with `short`, `long` etc and the rule will apply; C++ specifies that a bit more clearly.  The signedness of plain `char` is implementation-defined already, of course.

---

### Unsigned bit-fields

If the type of the bit-fields are unsigned, then the expression is fairly straight-forward:

```
int d = (example.a << 7) | example.b;
```

### Signed bit-fields

If the values are signed, then you have a major interpretation exercise to undertake, deciding what the value should be if `example.a` is negative and `example.b` is positive, or vice versa.  To some extent, the problem arises even if the values are both negative or both positive.

Suppose `example.a = 7;` and `example.b = 12;` — what should be the value of `d`?  Probably the same expression applies, but you could argue that it would be better to shift by 1 fewer places:

```
assert(example.a >= 0 && example.b >= 0);
int d = (example.a << 6) | example.b;      // Alternative interpretation
```

The other cases are left for you to decide; it depends on the interpretation you want to place on the values.  For example:

```
int d = ((example.a & 0x0F) << 7) | (example.b & 0x7F);
```

This forces the signed values to be treated as unsigned. It probably isn't what you're after.

---

### Modified question

> ```
> example.a = 1001     // binary
>
> example.b = 1010101  // binary
>
> d = 10011010101 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> ```
>
> where x can be 21 bits that belonged to d previously.

For this to work, then you need:

```
  d = (d & 0x001FFFFF) | ((((example.a & 0x0F) << 7) | (example.b & 0x7F)) << 21);
```

You probably can use fewer parentheses; I'm not sure I'd risk doing so.

### Union

However, with this revised specification, you might well be tempted to look at a `union` such as:

```
union u
{
    struct
    {
       int a:4;
       int b:7;
       int c:21;
    } y;
    int x;
} example;
```

However, the layout of the bits in the bit-fields w.r.t the bits in the `int x;` is not specified (they could be most significant bits first or least significant bits first), and there are always mutterings about 'if you access a value in a union that wasn't the last one assigned to you invoke undefined behaviour'.   Thus you have multiple platform-defined aspects of the bit field to deal with.  In fact, this sort of conundrum generally means that bit-fields are closely tied to one specific type of machine (CPU) and compiler and operating system.  They are very, very non-portable at the level of detail you're after.

Comment: +1: I still wonder why this was specced for `int` and not the other integer types (or were they and I'm reading the spec wrong?). I occasionally laugh when I see an `int x:1` to this day. The very idea of having a signed value of bit width-nothing still cracks me up.

Comment: @WhozCraig: See my note about the 'context of §6.7.2'.  The `int` is mentioned in the lines describing `short int` and `long long int`, etc, to I believe the point is covered.  Arguably, the C++ standard makes it clearer.